# How can I specify the D3 V4 micro library on CDN?

Tags: d3.js

**I want to load a microlibrary with cdn.**

・Is there a sample code that works normally somewhere?

---

▼index.html

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.js"></script>
```

▼js

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 1200])
    .range([0, 500]);
console.log(yScale(1200));
console.log(d3.version);
```

**Error**

> Uncaught TypeError: d3Color.cubehelix is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) is very clear about this: if you want to reference the microlibraries to use `d3.scale`, you have to reference all these:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-format.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Furthermore, the API says:

> You can omit d3-time and d3-time-format if you’re not using d3.scaleTime or d3.scaleUtc

Here is a demo:

```js
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([10, 1200])
  .range([0, 500]);
console.log(yScale(1200));
console.log(d3.version);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-format.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, `d3.version` only works with the default bundle, and will return `undefined` here.

Thus, an easier solution is just referencing the default bundle. For the minified one:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

And for the non-minified one:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Explanation It was easy to understand. Doubts solved thanks to you!